# How to login to Htcsense.com

Tags: htc-desire

I heard HTC is providing online services via [HTCSense.com](http://HTCSense.com). I have HTC Desire phone. How do I login to this site. when I open it it asks for authentication :(

**Update:** The service is live now. I just checked. Currently only two phones are supported: `Desire HD` and `Desire Z`. Heck I need for Desire :(

Comment: This isn't much of an Android question. I'm not sure that it belongs on this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working:

1. I registered a new account through my Mobile phone (HTC Desire HD, during phone setup).
2. I got an email from htc sense with a link in it to confirm my account
3. clicking the link open a page to htc sense, and tries to complete the registration and log you to your account page, but in my case it kept hanging
4. While in the confirmation page, I clicked on login again and were able to log in even though registration was still ongoing. Apparently the acocunt gets registered even though the page hangs.